Single variable equations using yacc and lex
I am making a chat using lex and yacc. Now the chat can answer different questions and make simple calculus using +, -, * and / . I want to add a functionality that permits the chat to do some simple single variable equations like ax+b=c or a+bx=c.I tried something but everytime it returns that the value of x = 0. I am not sure how to approach this problem.
%{
extern int yylval;
%}

%%

"salut" |
"Salut" |
"buna"  |
"Buna"  return SAL;

"Cu" |
"cu" return CU;

"Ce" |
"ce" return CE;

"Te"  |
"te"   return TE;

"Pot"  |
"pot"   return POT;

"Ajuta"  |
"ajuta"   return AJUTA;

"Astazi" |
"astazi" return ASTAZI;

"Ma" |
"ma" return MA;

"Poti" |
"poti" return POTI;

"La" |
"la" return LA;

"Tema" |
"tema" return TEMA;

"De" |
"de" return DE;

"Matematica" |
"matematica" |
"mate" return MATE;

"Imi" |
"imi" return IMI;

"Spui" |
"spui" return SPUI;

"Stii" |
"stii" return STII;

"Niste" |
"niste" return NISTE;

"Curiozitate" |
"curiozitate" return CURIOZITATE;

"O" |
"o" return O;

"Inseamna" |
"inseamna" return INSEAMNA;

"Face" |
"face" return FACE;

"Semnul" |
"semnul" return SEMNUL;

"Plus" |
"plus" return PLUS;

"Minus" |
"minus" return MINUS;

"Ori" |
"ori" |
"Inmultire" |
"inmultire" return INMULTIRE;

"Impartire" |
"impartire" return IMPARTIRE;

"Care" |
"care" return CARE;

"Este" |
"este" return ESTE;

"Ordinea" |
"ordinea" return ORDINEA;

"Efectuarii" |
"efectuarii" return EFECTUARII;

"Operatiilor" |
"operatiilor" return OPERATIILOR;

"Revedere" |
"revedere" return REVEDERE;

"Ne" |
"ne" return NE;

"Mai" |
"mai" return MAI;

"Auzim" |
"auzim" |
"Vedem" |
"vedem" return AUZIMVEDEM;

"Cum" |
"cum" return CUM;

"Numesti" |
"numesti" return NUMESTI;

"Cheama" |
"cheama" return CHEAMA;

"Urmatoarele" |
"urmatoarele" return URMATOARELE;

"Operatii" |
"operatii" return OPERATII;

"Explica" |
"explica" return EXPLICA;

"Functioneaza" |
"functioneaza" return FUNCTIONEAZA;


[A-Z]   {
        yylval = *yytext - 'A';
        return VARIABLE;
    }
[a-z]   {
        yylval = *yytext - 'a';
        return VARIABLE;
    }
[0-9]+  {
        yylval = strtol(yytext, (char **)NULL, *yytext=='0' ? 8:10);
        return INTEGER;
    }
0x[0-9a-fA-F]+  {
        yylval = strtol(yytext, (char **)NULL, 16);
        return INTEGER;
    }
[-()=+/*\n] return *yytext;
[ \t\r]+        ;

[\.\n\?!]     return ENDPROP;


.
%%

This is the yacc file where "ecuatie" and "solve_for_x" should resolve the equations.
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int variables[26];
int solve_for_x(int a, int b, int c, int sign);

extern int yylex(void);

char despreCuriozitati[50][600] = {
"Unele animale, cum ar fi broastele si serpii, isi pot inghiti hrana intreaga, deoarece au o mandibula flexibila.",
"Fibonacci a fost un matematician italian care a descoperit secventa Fibonacci, o serie de numere in care fiecare numar este suma celor doua anterioare.",
"Un fulg de zapada este un cristal de gheata care se formeaza atunci cand vapori de apa se condenseaza in atmosfera.",
"Un grup de lebede este cunoscut sub numele de banc.",
"Pangolinele sunt singurele mamifere acoperite complet cu solzi.",
"Un metru cub de miere poate cantari aproximativ 1.2 tone.",
"In timp ce Luna orbiteaza Pamantul, are si propriul sau satelit natural, numita Crucea Neagra.",
"In natura, exista aproximativ 10^18 furnici pe Pamant, adica aproximativ 1 milion de furnici pentru fiecare om.",
"Cand se apropie de Polul Nord, compasul magnetic se comporta ciudat, deoarece liniile de camp magnetic sunt foarte apropiate.",
"Broasca testoasa urca copaci!",
"Cifra pi (π) este un numar nesfarsit si irrational care incepe cu 3.14.",
"Liniile de pe palma ta sunt unice, la fel ca o amprenta digitala.",
"Coloana vertebrala a unui sarpe are sute de oase, comparativ cu cele 26-34 ale omului.",
"Luna are cratere din cauza impacturilor meteoritice.",
"Un fulger este de aproximativ 3 ori mai fierbinte decat suprafata Soarelui.",
"Ceasornicele au fost inventate acum aproximativ 5000 de ani in Mesopotamia.",
"Un leu poate dormi pana la 20 de ore pe zi.",
"Arborele de cacao, din care se fac ciocolata, creste in medie 6-12 metri inaltime.",
"In timp ce corpul uman este alcatuit in mare parte din apa, invelisul pamantului este alcatuit in mare parte din apa.",
"Un triunghi cu toate laturile egale se numeste triunghi echilateral.",
"Esarfa lui Moebius este un obiect matematic ciudat care are doar o fata si un singur margine.",
"Albinele comunica intre ele prin miscarea lor de dans.",
"In timp ce majoritatea pasarelor canta, cucul nu canta. In schimb, face un sunet numit „cucuiala”.",
"Lemniscata Bernoulli este o curba matematica care arata ca un „8” inclinat pe latura.",
"Planeta Venus este singura planeta din sistemul solar care se roteste in directie opusa fata de celelalte planete.",
"Un triunghi dreptunghic are un unghi drept, adica un unghi de 90 de grade.",
"Un lacusta poate sari pana la 20 de ori lungimea propriei sale corpuri.",
"Broastele pot sari de pana la 20 de ori inaltimea corpului lor.",
"Koalas isi petrec majoritatea vietii lor pe eucalipt, care este principala lor sursa de hrana.",
};

time_t t;
struct tm tm;
int ind  = 0;

%}

%token INTEGER VARIABLE
%token O FUNCTIONEAZA EXPLICA OPERATII URMATOARELE CUM NUMESTI CHEAMA ENDPROP SAL CU CE TE POT AJUTA ASTAZI MA POTI LA TEMA DE MATE IMI SPUI STII NISTE CURIOZITATE INSEAMNA FACE SEMNUL PLUS MINUS INMULTIRE IMPARTIRE CARE ESTE ORDINEA EFECTUARII OPERATIILOR REVEDERE NE MAI AUZIMVEDEM

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%%

program : program statement '\n'
        | program error '\n' { yyerrok; }
        | program salut_msg '\n'
        | program cumtenumesti '\n'
        | program ajutoroperatii '\n'
        | program plus '\n'
        | program minus '\n'
        | program inmultire '\n'
        | program impartire '\n'
        | program ordineoperatii '\n'
        | program curiozitati '\n'
        | program ecuatie '\n'
        | /* NULL */
        ;

statement : expression { printf("[CHAT]: %d\n>", $1); }
          | VARIABLE '=' expression { variables[$1] = $3; printf("[CHAT]: %c=%d\n>", $1 + 'a' - 1, $3); }
          | VARIABLE '+' '+' { variables[$1]++; printf("[CHAT]: %c=%d\n>", $1 + 'a' - 1, variables[$1]); }
          ;

expression : INTEGER
           | VARIABLE { $$ = variables[$1]; }
           | expression '+' expression { $$ = $1 + $3; }
           | expression '-' expression { $$ = $1 - $3; }
           | expression '*' expression { $$ = $1 * $3; }
           | expression '/' expression { $$ = $1 / $3; }
           | '(' expression ')' { $$ = $2; }
           ;

ecuatie : expression '=' expression { solve_for_x($1, $3, 0, 1); }
        | expression '+' VARIABLE '=' expression { solve_for_x($1, $4, 1, 1); }
        | expression '-' VARIABLE '=' expression { solve_for_x($1, $4, -1, 1); }
        | VARIABLE '+' expression '=' expression { solve_for_x($3, $4, 1, 0); }
        | VARIABLE '-' expression '=' expression { solve_for_x($3, $4, -1, 0); }
        ;

salut_msg : SAL ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: SALUTARE!\n>");}
          | SAL {printf("[CHAT]: SALUTARE!\n>");}
          ;

cumtenumesti : CUM TE NUMESTI ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Eu sunt Your Virtual Teacher! Sunt aici sa te ajut cu matematica si sa te invat despre curiozitatile lumii!\n>");}
             | CUM TE CHEAMA ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Eu sunt Your Virtual Teacher! Sunt aici sa te ajut cu matematica si sa te invat despre curiozitatile lumii!\n>");}
             ;

ajutoroperatii : MA POTI AJUTA CU URMATOARELE OPERATII ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Desigur!\n>");}
               | MA POTI AJUTA CU NISTE OPERATII ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Desigur!\n>");}
               ;

plus : IMI POTI EXPLICA CUM FUNCTIONEAZA SEMNUL PLUS ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Semnul plus\n Acest semn matematic, care arata ca o cruce (+), este folosit la notarea operatiei de adunare (de exemplu: 2 + 3). De asemenea, acesta poate indica numerele cu valori pozitive. Cuvantul „plus”, care este utilizat pentru a citi acest semn matematic, provine din limba latina, unde are intelesul de „mai mult”.!\n>");}

minus : IMI POTI EXPLICA CUM FUNCTIONEAZA SEMNUL MINUS ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Semnul minus\n Acest semn matematic, ce reprezinta o simpla linie (-), denota operatia de scadere. In limbajul matematic, simbolul dat mai este utilizat pentru a indica numerele cu valoare negativa. Cuvantul „minus” provine la fel din limba latina, unde are sensul de „mai putine”.\n De exemplu, pentru a evita scrierea pe lung a expresiei matematice „patru minus trei”, vom folosi semnul minus in modul urmator: 4 - 3.\n>");}

inmultire : IMI POTI EXPLICA CUM FUNCTIONEAZA SEMNUL INMULTIRE ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Semnul inmultirii\n Dupa cum spune si denumirea acestuia, semnul inmultirii este folosit pentru a nota operatia de inmultire. Acesta arata ca o cruce intoarsa la 45º sau ca minuscul literei X. In propozitiile matematice, acest semn se citeste „ori” sau „inmultit cu”. Deci, in loc sa scriem „doi ori doi”, vom nota „2 x 2”.\n>");}

impartire : IMI POTI EXPLICA CUM FUNCTIONEAZA SEMNUL IMPARTIRE ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Semnul impartirii\n Daca am lua semnul scaderii (-) si l-am „imbratisa” din ambele parti cu cate un punct (:), atunci vom obtine semnul impartirii (÷). Acest simbol, insa, nu este singurul mod de a nota operatia de impartire. Se mai folosesc si urmatoarele semne: doua puncte (:), bara oblica (/) si linia de fractie (—). In propozitiile matematice, semnul impartirii este citit „impartit la”.\n>");}

ordineoperatii : CARE ESTE ORDINEA OPERATIILOR ENDPROP {printf("[CHAT]: Acestea sunt operatiile matematice pe care le cunoastem pana acum: adunarea, scaderea, inmultirea si impartirea. Le putem considera specii diferite, de exemplu: adunarea o putem considera asemanatoare cu un pui, scaderea cu un boboc, inmultirea cu o vulpe, iar impartirea cu un lup. Acum sa ne imaginam un concurs de alergari intre aceste patru vietati. Cam cine credeti ca ar castiga: puiul, bobocul, vulpea sau lupul? Cam in acesti termeni trebuie sa vedem atunci cand ne gandim la ordinea efectuarii operatiilor. Inmultirea si impartirea sunt primele, apoi urmeaza adunarea si scaderea. In concluzie, daca avem inmultire sau impartire, ele se rezolva primele, apoi de la stanga la dreapta adunarile si scaderile.\n>");}

curiozitati : IMI SPUI O CURIOZITATE ENDPROP {
                printf("[CHAT]: Da! Uite una:\n");
                t = time(NULL);
                tm = *localtime(&t);
                ind = tm.tm_sec % 30;
                printf("[CHAT]: %s\n>",despreCuriozitati[ind]);
            }

            | STII O CURIOZITATE ENDPROP{
                printf("[CHAT]: Da! Uite una:\n");
                t = time(NULL);
                tm = *localtime(&t);
                ind = tm.tm_sec % 30;
                printf("[CHAT]: %s\n>",despreCuriozitati[ind]);
            }

stop  : LA REVEDERE ENDPROP {printf("Iti doresc o zi buna!\n"); exit(0);}
      | NE MAI AUZIMVEDEM ENDPROP {printf("Iti doresc o zi buna!\n"); exit(0);}

%%

int solve_for_x(int a, int b, int c, int sign) {
    // a * x + b = c sau a + x * b = c
    int x_value = 0;
    if (sign == 1) {
        // cazurile cu '+' si '-'
        if (a == 0 && b != 0) {
            x_value = c - b;
        } else if (b == 0 && a != 0) {
            x_value = (c - b) / a;
        } else {
            x_value = (c - a) / b;
        }
    } else {
        x_value = (b - a);
    }
    printf("[CHAT]: Value of x is: %d\n>", x_value);
    return x_value;
}

#include "lex.yy.c"

int main() {
        printf("------------------------------------------\n\n");
        printf("        Your Virtual Teacher!        \n\n");
        printf("-------------------------------------------\n\n> ");
        yyparse();
}
int yyerror() {printf("Instructiune neacceptata! La revedere!\n");}


First check if solve_for_x gets the right values of a, b, c, and sign. If they are right, it's not a problem with parsing. If they are not, track the exact point in the program where the value starts to be incorrect for the first time. If after finding the source of the problem you still don't understand it, write a question here.
